# Sass style options ignored in Gruntfile

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I have the following `gruntfile`, that compiles fine, however it appears to be ignore the `style` option and only use the default 'nested' style. I've tried `compressed`, `expanded` and `compact` and they all come out exactly the same.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'css/style.css' : 'scss/main.scss'
        },
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          style: 'expanded'
        }
      }
    },
    sass_globbing: {
      your_target: {
        files: {
          'scss/_base.scss': 'scss/base/**/*.scss',
          'scss/_layout.scss': 'scss/layout/**/*.scss',
          'scss/_components.scss': 'scss/components/**/*.scss',
          'scss/_theme.scss': 'scss/theme/**/*.scss'
        },
        options: {
          useSingleQuoates: false
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      dist: {
        options : {
          browsers: ['last 2 version','ie 8','ie 9','android 4']
        },
        files: {
          'css/style.css' : 'css/style.css'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      css: {
        files: '**/*.scss',
        tasks: ['sass_globbing','sass','autoprefixer']
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass-globbing');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

I'm using:

- grunt-cli v1.2.0
- grunt v0.4.5

I've tried adding changes to the scss files, deleting the stylesheet, generating a totally new file with a different name, running `grunt sass --force` and it still generates the same file (and it is generating the file). I've also tried overriding the style in grunt with `grunt sass --style compact --force`, and still no joy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass#usage, the `options` key goes one level higher (Move it out of `dist`):

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            style: 'compressed'
        },
        dist: {
            ...
       }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!